# Get info for Common Log Format from socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I want to create a log file for my webserver written in C under UNIX.

The logfile should be formatted according to [Common Log Format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_common.html), but I don't know how to get the ident and authuser from the connecting socket.

Is there a simple way to get these from the socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User name is not an attribute of socket - you need to get it from HTTP request, so sockets API can't help you on this.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find it in the HTTP request. Where can I find it?

Comment: See HTTP RFC for HTTP header - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.3
Authorization is what you need.
Also see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication